# change iTextSharp Font Color in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to change font color. I use `SetRGBColorStroke`, `SetColorFill`, `SetColorStroke` but those didn't work. My code is below.

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(outputPdfPath);
var stream = File.OpenWrite(path);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5;
float scale = 1f;
int xs = 35; int ys = 726;
int xtemp = 0; int ytemp = 0;
document.Open();
PdfContentByte pb = writer.DirectContent;
PdfContentByte pbtext = writer.DirectContent;

for (int j = 1; j <= reader2.NumberOfPages; j++)
{
    document.NewPage();
    //PdfContentByte pbtext;
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.TTF", BaseFont.WINANSI, true);
    ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();//simple read with accessible
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader2, j);
    pb.AddTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, xtemp, ytemp);


    if (j == 1)
    {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Chunk(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(04.04F, 14.04F, BaseColor.BLACK, 100, -46)));
        document.Add(p);

        pbtext = writer.DirectContent;
        pbtext.BeginText();
        pbtext.SetFontAndSize(bf, 4);
        pbtext.SetRGBColorStroke(255, 0, 0);
        pbtext.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, namafile.Substring(0, 12), 292.0f, 740f, 0);
       // pbtext.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
       // pbtext.setColorFill(new BaseColor(255, 0, 0, 50));
       // pbtext.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
        pbtext.EndText();


    }
}

//reader2.Close();

document.Close();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to change font color inside a paragraph?

Comment: change text in here  pbtext.ShowTextAligned

Comment: So what happens? What do you expect and what do you get actually? What doesn't work?

Comment: Usually fonts provide outlines which are filled. Thus, you'll need the fill color. You claim you have tried that, too. What exactly was the result then?

Comment: solved with this code:
pbtext.setColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
pbtext.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, namafile.Substring(0, 12), 292.0f, 740f, 0);

my mistake put setfillcolor in bottom.

Comment: seriously ... if you are using dotnet core you should try generating Pdf using nodejs ... this whole Itextsharp thing is way too complicated

Comment: @Rajaji iText 5 .NET (formerly known as iTextSharp) can be a bit convoluted, that's why I recommend iText 7, which is a complete rewrite of iText and generally you need less lines of code to do the same. Node.js is an entirely different technology stack than Dotnet Core.

Comment: sure https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-export-HTML-to-PDF-c5afd0ce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved with this code:

```
pbtext.setColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
pbtext.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, namafile.Substring(0, 12), 292.0f, 740f, 0);
```

my mistake put setfillcolor in bottom